# Wordpress Search not Showing exact result for pages

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a wordpress site with following Search function, it works fine with some pages but when i use exact same title on search it doesnt show some pages. What might be the reason for it?  Please can anyone help me to sort out this issue.
Big thanks in advance

```
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('header-link'); ?>
                <div class="clear" style="clear:both; width:100%; height:auto;"></div>
<div class="content">  
<?php dynamic_sidebar('mobile-widget'); ?> 
    <div class="mainbar">

        <?php the_post(); ?>

        <div class="article">
            <?php if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar-1')) : ?>
                <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
                </div><!-- #secondary -->
            <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>



                <h1 class="page-title"> <?php  echo get_theme_mod('search_result_text', 'Search Results Found For'); ?> <span><?php the_search_query(); ?></span></h1>


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'evotis'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true); ?></a></h2>



                    <div class="entry-summary">   
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true); ?>
                 <div class="h-readmore"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_theme_mod('readmore', 'Lees artikel'); ?></a></div>
                    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->


                </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
                <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'evotis' )) ?></div>
                    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'evotis' )) ?></div>
                </div><!-- #nav-below -->
<?php } ?>            


<?php else : ?>

                <div id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'evotis' ) ?></h2>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'evotis' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>                       
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </div>

<?php endif; ?>   


            <?php if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar-2')) : ?>
                <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2'); ?>
                </div><!-- #secondary -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>      
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

searchform.php code is like below

```
<div class="searchform search" rol="search">

 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">

        <input type="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php echo get_theme_mod('search_placeholder', 'Search: Enter Your keywords'); ?> "/>

        <input type="submit" class="sbutton" alt="Search" value="search"/>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code on your function.php

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```